# deviceready always fired on second page and not on first page

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am beginner to phonegap framework developing the andriod App. I have following problem:

I have following page structure:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
     <head>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function onDeviceReady(){
                                                alert("Device Ready")                                                
                                              }, true);

    });
   </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="page1" data-role="page" data-quicklinks="true" > 
  <a href="#page2"> Go to Page 2</a>
</div>

<div id="page2" data-role="page" data-quicklinks="true" > 
  <a href="#page1"> Go to Page 1</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open the document, I see the contents of #page1, but can't see the alert of "Device Ready", but when I click on link to #page2, the "Device Ready" alert comes up. I want device ready to be fired when I first open the page1, really not sure how to deal with it. I tried inserting the JS code inside the #page1 div, still no effect.

Please tell me where am I going wrong.

---

Here is the full code I am using:
I am having the jQuery libraries stored in my local folder as I need to run offline.
also have cordova.js in the local folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
 <script src="jquery_mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.js"></script>

  <!--PhoneGap Libraries --> 
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="page1" data-role="page" data-quicklinks="true" > 
    <a href="#page2" rel="external"> Go to Page 2</a>
  </div>

  <div id="page2" data-role="page" data-quicklinks="true" > 
    <a href="#page1" rel="external"> Go to Page 1</a>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function onDeviceReady(){
      alert("Device Ready");                                                
    }, true);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post the whole html file. When are you adding the jQuery and jQuery mobile libraries?

Comment: Any luck here? I am in the same problem...

Comment: Hi @leo2_uru, did not found the exact solution for the problem, but created a following work around:

I needed the cordova on 2nd page actually, so I just imported the scripts on first page, and did nothing and created link to 2nd page from 1st page. So when I went on 2nd page, the device ready got fired :) ... I don't know this is exact solution or not, but it worked ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to remove the **$** function call and place it directly in the `<script>` tag as shown below

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   document.addEventListener("deviceready", function onDeviceReady(){
                                                alert("Device Ready")                                                
                                              }, true);

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Frank, have tried the same thing, still have to click the link to 2nd page to get the alert.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the script at the end of the page :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="page1" data-role="page" data-quicklinks="true" > 
    <a href="#page2"> Go to Page 2</a>
  </div>

  <div id="page2" data-role="page" data-quicklinks="true" > 
    <a href="#page1"> Go to Page 1</a>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function onDeviceReady(){
      alert("Device Ready")                                                
    }, true);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Thom, tried your suggestion, still no luck! :(

Answer (score 0):

Add the jquery mobile libraries & cordova.js

```
<!--jquery mobile libraries -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Then

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.addEventListener("deviceready", function onDeviceReady(){ alert("Device Ready") }, true);

</script>
```